# Angular ngRoute: How to temporarily disable reloadOnSearch?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

In AngularJS 1.4.8 with [ngRoute](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ngRoute), I am trying to capture search parameters from the URL and then clear them from the URL *without* reloading the route. This can be achieved easily enough by setting `reloadOnSearch: false` in my route config. However, after clearing the search parameters from the URL, I do want my route to reload on search.

Is it possible to temporarily enable/disable `reloadOnSearch`, or do I need to disable it and then manually trigger a reload using [$route.reload()](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route#reload)?

Here is my current configuration:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(routeConfig)
  .controller('MyViewController', MyViewController)
;

function routeConfig($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: 'MyViewController',
      controllerAs: 'myView',
      reloadOnSearch: false,
      template: '<h1>Search Params</h1><ul><li ng-repeat="(key, value) in myView.params">{{key}}: {{value}}</li></ul>'
    })
    .otherwise('/')
  ;
}

function MyViewController($location) {
  var myView = this;
  myView.params = $location.search();
  $location.search({});
}
```

Ideally, after calling `$location.search({});` I would like to set `reloadOnSearch: true`.